# Is there a way to download neo4j result as a csv

Tags: neo4j

I am using ne04j community version 1.9.8. I created a query that gives the result in a table format. It has 5 columns (c1-c5) and each column's data will need to be created as a different csv file. Is there any way command that I can use to parse the result into csvs?

I have seen the csv import to neo4j but I need the exact opposite way here. Thanks for your help.

[Edited]

Here is my original query:

```
START survey=node(1111111)
MATCH surveyQ-[:lastStep]->surveyQStep-[:surveys]->survey-[:questionpanel]->qstn-[:se‌​ctions]->s-[:questions]->q-[:answers]->answers
RETURN ID(survey) as surveyID, ID(qstn) as questionpanelID, ID(s) as sectionID, ID(q) as questionID, ID(answers) as answerID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

*This answer only applies to newer versions of neo4j that support the WHEN and CASE clauses, not 1.9.8. If upgrading to, say, 2.1.5 is not possible, it should be possible to install a separate instance of neo4j 2.1.5, copy the data over to the new instance, and use this answer on the new instance.*

You can use Cypher to generate a comma-delimited result for each column, one at a time. You can then copy the  result for each column into a separate file.

Let's suppose your original query ended in `RETURN a, b, c, d, e;`

To get the a comma-delimited value for all the values in the fourth column (i.e., variable `d`), you can replace your `RETURN` clause with the following:

```
WITH COLLECT(d) AS v
RETURN reduce(s = "", x IN v | s + (CASE WHEN s = "" THEN "" ELSE "," END ) + x);
```

Based your original query, this is how you'd get the CSV data for the first column:

```
START survey=node(1111111)
MATCH surveyQ-[:lastStep]->surveyQStep-[:surveys]->survey-[:questionpanel]->qstn-[:se‌​ctions]->s-[:questions]->q-[:answers]->answers
WITH COLLECT(ID(survey)) AS surveyID
RETURN reduce(s = "", x IN surveyID | s + (CASE WHEN s = "" THEN "" ELSE "," END ) + x);
```

Comment: Thank you, it complains of an unclosed parentheses. Also could you please briefly describe as to what all these variables are? Again, I am a newbie here trying to figure things out. Thanks again!

Comment: Please provide your original query, and then maybe I can give you an answer that directly applies to your situation.

Comment: START
 survey=node(1111111)
MATCH
 surveyQ-[:lastStep]->surveyQStep-[:surveys]->survey-[:questionpanel]->qstn-[:sections]->s-[:questions]->q-[:answers]->answers
RETURN
 ID(survey) as surveyID, ID(qstn) as questionpanelID, ID(s) as sectionID, ID(q) as questionID, ID(answers) as answerID

Comment: OK, I've added an example to my answer, using your original query. Hopefully this will help. You can also refer to the [cheat sheet for 1.9](http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/1.9/) for some info on the syntax.
But I now see that that document does not mention the CASE clause -- is it possible that 1.9.8 does not support that? If not, then this specific answer will obviously not work for you.

Comment: The [reference for 1.9.9](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.9/cypher-query-lang.html) does not document the WHEN and CASE clauses. And neither does the reference for 2.0.4. So, those were aded fairly recently.

Comment: Thanks that helps. I will update neo4j and see if I can work with the example.

Comment: The answer by @michaelhunger should also work for you in 2.1.5.

Answer (score 1):

You can also download the data from a query in the neo4j-browser as CSV if you're in the tabular view and hit the small download icon on the top-right within that table-frame.

Otherwise, if a command-line tool is better suited for you,

check out the `-o`utput option of the `cypher-import` command of the neo4j-shell-tools: https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#cypher-import

Comment: Thank you, I tried the command line output but I was not successful. Also I could not find the "download icon" in 1.9.8 version. Could you please point me to it or add a small image as to where I could find it. I am a newbie here trying to figure things out. Thanks again!